# Arithmetic PHP in devision of 2 numbers

Tags: php, devise

I allready got this code working, it deviedes 2 numbers, but the problem here is that I have a file named `index.php` so the function will be called on the same page. But by first load there shows a error that says

`Warning: Division by zero in /home/u482355755/public_html/index.php on line 4`

So how to tell the function to not deviede numbers before they are entered?

```
<?php
       $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
       $value2 = $_POST['value2'];
       $value3 = $value1 / $value2;
?>
<html>
       <title>PHP - Add two numbers</title>
       <body>
              <form action="index.php" method="post">
                     <input type="text" name="value1" value="<?php if ($value1 == "") { echo "0"; } else { echo $value1; } ?>" />
                     <input type="text" name="value2" value="<?php echo $value2 ?>" />
                     <input type="submit" value="Calculate values"/>
              </form>
              Answer : <?php echo $value3; ?>
       </body>
</html>
```

Im a student of programming so that explains that coding is to me new, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { // did you sent the form?`

Comment: Sorry not needed, Ive got the answer below so it works like a charm! But anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small change on PHP code to execute only after form submitted:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['value1']) && isset($_POST['value2'])){
   $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
   $value2 = $_POST['value2'];
   $value3 = $value1 / $value2;
}

?>
```

Comment: Ive searched for something like that, so done and thanks a lot!